# ¿Como llenar un objeto y guardarlo en un ArrayList con datos pedidos al usuario?

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans-11

tengo un ArrayList que debo llenar con datos pedidos a los usuarios, lo necesito en arraylist porque la manipulación de los datos es más fácil con ellos

Mi main es `Biblioteca`, y tengo mi clase `Lector` en ella tengo los atributos privados nombre, retraso, días y código del libro a prestar; el objetivo es que un lector pueda prestar y/o devolver un libro. Para poder hacer todo ésto tengo que saber los nombres de cada uno, código del libro que van a prestar, y los días que van a tener el libro. Si quieren prestar un libro los añado a una lista prestar, y si quieren devolver un libro, simplemente los elimino del ArrayList.

El problema está en que no se cómo guardar una cantidad ilimitada de objetos(Lectores) en un arrayList, ir llenando los datos en tiempo de ejecución. El otro problema que tengo es que me genera error a la hora de mandar a imprimir el ArrayList. Intenté algo así:

```
package biblioteca;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lector {
    private String nombre;
    private int dias;
    private int retraso;

    public Lector(String nombre, int dias, int retraso) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.dias = dias;
        this.retraso = retraso;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getDias() {
        return dias;
    }

    public void setDias(int dias) {
        this.dias = dias;
    }

    public int getRetraso() {
        return retraso;
    }

    public void setRetraso(int retraso) {
        this.retraso = retraso;
    }

    public Lector() {}
    
    private ArrayList<Lector> lectores;
    
    public ArrayList getLectores(){
      
        Scanner cin = new Scanner (System.in); 
        lectores = new ArrayList<Lector>();
        Lector lec = new Lector();

        System.out.println("Escriba su nombre: ");
        String name = cin.next();
        lec.setNombre(name);
        System.out.println("Escriba el dia: ");
        int di = cin.nextInt();
        lec.setDias(di);
        System.out.println("Escriba el retraso: ");
        int re = cin.nextInt();
        lec.setRetraso(re);
        
        lectores.add(new Lector(name,di,re));
        
        System.out.println("Desea ver el arraylist: \n1-Si \n2-No");
        int selec =cin.nextInt();
        
        if(selec==1){
            for (int t=0;t<=lectores.size();t++){
                System.out.println(lectores.get(t));
            }
        }
        
        return lectores;
    }

    }
```

En el main solo mando a llamar al método `lector.getLectores();`
Hoy inicie a usar los ArrayList y agradecería mucho que me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: Te felicito, el codigo se encuentra en su mayor parte organizado y bien identado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes 2 problemas, el primero es que en cada vez que llamas al metodo `getLectores` estas reiniciando la memoria del `ArrayList`:

```
lectores = new ArrayList<Lector>();
```

Para conservar la memoria de ese `ArrayList` te propongo directamente iniciarlo en los dos constructores y **NO** volverlo a iniciar nunca mas en ninguna otra parte:

```
...
private ArrayList<Lector> lectores;

public Lector(String nombre, int dias, int retraso) {
    ...
    this.lectores = new ArrayList<>();
}

public Lector(){
   this.lectores = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

El segundo error es que los arreglos empiezan desde el `0`, por lo que la condicion que tienes en el ciclo siempre te va a dar un error:

```
for (int t=0;t<=lectores.size();t++)
```

Esto debido a que tanto `size()` para un `ArrayList` como `length` para un Array normal de toda la vida **te devuelven el tamaño del array pero contando desde 1 y no desde el 0**, para solucionarlo la condicion **NO** debe ser `<=` (menor o igual) si no `<` (menor).

Comment: Gracias, el error se ha solucionado, también el de mandar a imprimir.